# Проблема в Joomla, в том что не открывается Media Manager

Tags: joomla

[image: вот такое]

Проблема в Joomla, в том что не открывается Media Manager... Помогите ребят...

Comment: Трудно угадать что вы там сделали, возможно проблема с хостингом,браузером,антивирусом, фаерволом и т.д Данный Media Manager был работающим и после каких ваших действий стал не рабочим? вы что то меняли, устанавливали  или обновляли в Joomla?

Comment: Да после обновления так получилось....

Comment: ну тогда в настройках поставьте вывод ошибок на Maximum и попробуйте найти что за конфликт